# React native best practices for modules integration

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have implemented a react native module that requires multidex enabled on Android (and other small changes). 
Every time the users want to use the module, these are the steps I suggest:

- Create the app with `react-native init YourApp`
- Install react-native-my_module from GitHub: `yarn add github:MyRepo/react-native`
- Link module react-native-my_module: `react-native link react-native-my_module`
- Manually edit `YourApp/android/app/build.gradle`, and add `multiDexEnabled true` (and other small changes)

Is there a more elegant way to simplify the last step?
I would like to keep integration steps simpler as possible.
I'm wondering if there is a configuration option that would do that automagically during the linking process.

Comment: I don't think that there is way but.. why don't you make it yourself? You're using node anyways so why not create a simple script with `fs` and let edit the build file for you?

Comment: @Raymond you mean this https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html? Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Yes exactly. You probably only need `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` and since all of the projects are inside `dependencies`, I do not think it'll be that hard to append the new project